# Is it possible to have multiple data sources in coded ui test

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to set up a Coded UI test and have the desire to pull values from two separate data sources (in this case xml files).  I have been doing this with just one data source many times but have a couple questions concerning multiple sources.

1. Is it possible to have two data sources for the same Coded UI test?
2. If so, how do you differentiate between them when reading values -
   when using just one data source I use the
   'this.TestContext.DataRow["blah"].toString();' method.

Thanks in advance for any help

erik

Finally found something (not sure how I missed it the first time) which indicates there can be only one TestMethod attribute per Test method (duh to me).  So, I guess my refined question is; is there a way around that limitation?  This is a long shot I know but would simplify things.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have more than one Data Source for Single Test, But if your test needs data to be read from two different sources then you can write your custom code to read values from external source in between the test.

i.e. You can have one Data source which controls the iteration of test and other one in your custom code to get value for each iteration of test.

Comment: Thank you much, not sure I'll bother because it is a 'want' not a 'need' but good to know regardless.

Answer (score 0):

We have tests here which read multiple data sources. You can put the connections to the data sources in a separate class (you can put them in the same function, just call the function once to open them) then reference the data sources from wherever you need them.

As for the [Test Method] issue, the same applies. You can place [Test Method] in the second class before the function with the data sources.